# Google play shows invalid warning when releasing app bundle

Tags: android, google-play, android-billing, play-billing-library

Recently google play started to show an invalid warning when I try to release to production a new version of my app

> We've detected this app uses an unsupported version of Play billing.
> Please upgrade to Billing Library version 3 or newer to publish this
> app. Learn More about Billing Library 3.

The problem is that I don't import any version of google play billing, neither i declare billig permission in my manifest.

Although google play always shows the warning it lets me ignore and proceed, but it kind of makes me worry thinking that one of the libraries I import is using this deprecated version of Play Billing...

I've ran gradle dependency tree check and absolutely no mention to `billingclient` nor `billing` was found.

Does anyone have a similar error? what is the cause?

Comment: I get the same error.  No idea why.  My app doesn't offer any purchases.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the com.android.vending.BILLING permission declared in your manifest? You can see view your APK manifest by running apkanalyzer manifest print .